# Forcing Gibbon Gem (or Faraday) to use QuotaGuard Static HTTP proxy on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, mailchimp, faraday

Full disclaimer; I'm not a strong Ruby dev, but I am learning quickly :)

I've set up a simple Ruby script on a Heroku dyno that listens for calls from our donation platform.

When a donation is made, it hits a webhook endpoint within my app, which then sends a donation receipt via Mandrill (which works fine), and updates/inserts a record in a Mailchimp list, via the 'upsert' method of the wonderful Gibbon gem.

That all works fine; except when the Heroku box happens to come up on an IP address that has done something bad in the past, and Mailchimp's API drops with a 403 (Forbidden) error.

I've had this confirmed by the Mailchimp API team; they suggest using something like [QuotaGuard Static](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/quotaguardstatic) to tunnel the API requests to Mailchimp through, removing the issue of API calls from inconsistent (and sometimes untrusted) IP addresses.

I'd love some advice on how to make this happen. I can see that Gibbon uses Faraday to handle HTTP requests, but I'm not an advanced enough Ruby dev to fork the code and add in HTTP proxy functionality.

If there's a way to globally force the Faraday calls to use a HTTP proxy (ie QuotaGuard Static), that's what I'm looking for. A config setting for Faraday, for example.

Or perhaps there's a tweak I can make to my Procfile:

```
web: bundle exec ruby webhooks.rb -p $PORT
```

...that will force the outbound traffic to go via the QuotaGuard Static proxy. I know [Proximo](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/proximo) has this functionality, but it also blocks inbound access to the app, which doesn't work for this app.

Appreciate any ideas the community can offer. Thanks!

Comment: @marco-sandrini - I feel a little silly for not working that out, but - I'm thrilled it was that easy to fix. Thank you!

Comment: I am happy I could help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Faraday documentation ([here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/lostisland/faraday/Faraday/Connection)) the `Connection`class uses the proxy specified in the `http_proxy` environment variable. I have never tried it, but looking at the source code it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Gibbon Author here. You can simply set the proxy value to the proxy URL in Gibbon 2.2.0 and later.

Comment: Hi @Amro - sorry, I've been away on holidays. Thanks for the tip, and the **awesome** gem. We use it a heap :)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to provide a bit more information, since the two answers pointed me on the right track but still required me to do some digging. I solved this issue by first adding the `QuotaGuard Static` add-on in Heroku (free for up to 250 uses per month) and then initializing Gibbon like so:

```
g = Gibbon::Request.new
g.proxy = ENV["QUOTAGUARDSTATIC_URL"]
```

And here is the relevant section from the Gibbon docs: https://github.com/amro/gibbon#other